# Shape problem building a nn model with keras in model.fit() function

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory, shapes

So I'm working on this code to build a nn with keras. My dataset is about breast cancer diagnosis and I have already done the preprocessing.
I am building the model, and everthing was fine until I got a shape error.
My code the following:

```
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy

model = keras.Sequential()
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        #Capa 1
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(13, 16)
        #Capa 2
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 1)
        pass

    def forward(self, x):
        # Capa 1
        x = self.linear1(x)
        #Activem la primera capa
        x = F.relu(x)
        #Capa 2
        x = self.linear2(x)
        #Activem la segona capa
        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        #pass
        return x
model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(13,), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(16,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

loss_function = BinaryCrossentropy()
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-4)

model.compile(
    optimizer = optim, 
    loss = loss_function,
    metrics= 'accuracy'
)
```

The following part is where I get the error

```
model.fit(
    x=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=16,
    epochs=50,
    verbose="auto",
    callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    shuffle=True,
    class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None,
    initial_epoch=0,
    steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None,
    validation_batch_size=None,
    validation_freq=1,
)
```

The error that keeps showing is:
"*ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 13), found shape=(16, 30)*"

I do not understand how to fix the error, since it's the first time I try to build a keras nn model myself and the layer specifications have been given to me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe you should change values in layer - to have `(16, 30)`. Or maybe you have to `transpose` data to change shape from `(30, 16)` to `(16, 30)`

Comment: Are you using the NeuralNetwork class somewhere?